# Clone Retrofit 2 Response object in Interceptor

Tags: android, retrofit, interceptor

**Problem**

I want to use Custom Interceptor to catch data before it sends to `onResponse` in code.
This is my `Interceptor` code:

```
public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();

        try {
            Response response = chain.proceed(request);
            Response savedResponse = response.newBuilder().build();

            if (savedResponse.isSuccessful()){
                String result = savedResponse.body().string();
                ApiInterceptor apiInterceptor = new Gson().fromJson(result, ApiInterceptor.class);

                Log.i("hieu", "");
                if (activity != null){
                    if (apiInterceptor.getApi_result() != null){
                        if (apiInterceptor.getApi_result().getMainte() == AppConstants.MAINTENANCE_CODE){
                            // show maintenance activity
                        }else{
                            if (apiInterceptor.getApi_result().getTransfer_status() == AppConstants.TRANSFERING_CODE){
                                // hien thi man hinh chuyen doi

                            }else{
                                if (apiInterceptor.getApi_result().getOnly_payment_status() == AppConstants.ONLY_PAYMENT_CODE){
                                    // hien thi man hinh qua han
                                }else{
                                    if (apiInterceptor.getApi_result().getResult() != 0){
                                        showMessage(apiInterceptor.getApi_result().getMessage());
                                    }else{
                                        // normal
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }else{
                showMessage(savedResponse.message());
            }

            return savedResponse;
        }catch (Exception e){
            LogUtils.d(SettingInterceptor.this.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage());
            if (activity != null)
                showMessage(activity.getString(R.string.network_error));
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

Since I know i only can access only 1 time to response after `chain.proceed`, I want to clone that response so I can access and process more than 1 time with that response. So I used

`Response savedResponse = response.newBuilder().build();`

But when i run on debug mode, this code run more than 1 time.

First time, `result` returns correct JSON data. After debug line run to `return savedResponse;` it run again started at `Response savedResponse = response.newBuilder().build();` and `savedResponse.isSuccessful() return success` but `result` return blank string.

How to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create custom callbacks.

Custom Response Interceptor

```
public abstract class CustomCallbacks implements Callback {

    public abstract void onCustomResponse(Call call, Response response);

    public abstract void onCustomFailure(Call call, Throwable response);

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) {
        //TODO: process response here
        if(response.isSuccessful()) {
            onCustomResponse(call, response);
        }else{
           onCustomFailure(call, new Exception("request failed"));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call call, Throwable t) {
        onCustomFailure(call, t);
    }
}
```

Implementation

```
call.enqueue(new CustomCallbacks() {
            @Override
            public void onCustomResponse(Call call, Response response) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCustomFailure(Call call, Throwable response) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Can you explain more? Where why I need callback and where to put your code in? Because I think code inside interceptor is sequentially.

Comment: why do you want to process response more than 1 time?

Comment: Sorry. I think I describe problem not pure. Is program run more than 1, not what i want sir. It run mutiple times and from 2nd time, it return blank string.